# Writing a vbscript to read data in a table and output total hours

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am working with a table like below, where there are projects that are broken down into tasks, and one task may appear more than once. I am aiming to get the sum of all hours of the same task, so for example the total hours for task 1 = 33 hours.

<kbd>Project Name</kbd><kbd>Task Name</kbd><kbd>Hours</kbd>
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>7</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>7</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>7</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 2</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 2</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 2</kbd>      <kbd>15</kbd>    
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 2</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 2</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 3</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 3</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 1</kbd>      <kbd>Task 3</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>7</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 4</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 4</kbd>      <kbd>7</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 4</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 4</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 5</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 5</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      
<kbd>Project 2</kbd>      <kbd>Task 5</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>

This is the output that I am aiming for:

<kbd>Project 1</kbd><kbd>Hours</kbd>
<kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>33</kbd>      
<kbd>Task 2</kbd>      <kbd>29</kbd>      
<kbd>Task 3</kbd>      <kbd>10</kbd>

<kbd>Project 2</kbd><kbd>Hours</kbd>
<kbd>Task 1</kbd>      <kbd>14</kbd>      
<kbd>Task 4</kbd>      <kbd>15</kbd>      
<kbd>Task 5</kbd>      <kbd>10</kbd>

The table is ordered by project name and they are also a unique name, however the tasks may not be unique, as to say Task 1 may appear in project 1 and project 2, but should only be totaled for project 1, where the project name is project 1.

I have been using powershell to try and get to that output for days now but to no avail. Powershell is probably a little un orthodox, so I am thinking vb is the answer. I am not too experienced in vb so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to do this in `vbscript` or in `VBA` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept for solving the problem of selecting and aggregating data from a table are SQL, SELECT, WHERE and GROUP BY. Using SQL from VBA or VBScript means ADO (Connection, Recordset). The syntactical differences between VBScript and VBA are just a minor inconvenience (start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info)). Proof of concept VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

Const adClipString = 2

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

WScript.Quit demoMain()

Function demoMain()
  demoMain = 0 ' assume success

  Dim sDDir   : sDDir    = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\Data\sumhours")
  Dim sFiNa   : sFiNa    = "hours.txt"
  Dim sFSpec  : sFSpec   = goFS.BuildPath(sDDir, sFiNa)
  goFS.CreateTextFile(sFSpec, True).WriteLine Join(Array( _
        "A;B;C" _
      , "1;100;10" _
      , "1;200;20" _
      , "1;100;10" _
      , "2;100;99" _
  ), vbCrLf)
  Dim sC      : sC       = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=" & sDDir & ";"
  Dim oXDb    : Set oXDb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  oXDb.open sC
  WScript.Echo Join(Split("A B C"), vbTab)
  WScript.Echo oXDb.Execute("SELECT * FROM [" & sFiNa & "]").GetString(adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf)
  WScript.Echo oXDb.Execute("SELECT SUM(C) FROM [" & sFiNa & "] WHERE A = 1 AND B = 100").GetString(adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf)
  WScript.Echo oXDb.Execute("SELECT A, B, SUM(C) FROM [" & sFiNa & "] GROUP BY A, B").GetString(adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf)
  oXDb.Close

End Function ' demoMain
```

output:

```
cscript 16504304.vbs
A       B       C
1       100     10
1       200     20
1       100     10
2       100     99

20

1       100     20
1       200     20
2       100     99
```

**Update:**

VBA 'implemenation':

```
Option Explicit

' code.xls, accesses sumhours.xls
' Ref to ADO (2.8)

Sub Main()
  Dim oXDb As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim sSC: sSC = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8328305\data\sumhours\sumhours.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
  oXDb.Open sSC
  Debug.Print oXDb.Execute("SELECT SUM(C) FROM [Tbl1] WHERE A=1 AND B=100").GetString(2, 2, vbTab, vbCrLf)
  oXDb.Close
End Sub
```

Powershell 'implementation':

```
$sSC = 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8328305\data\sumhours\sumhours.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"'
$oXDb = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection 
$oXDb.Open($sSC)
echo $oXDb.Execute("SELECT A, B, SUM(C) FROM [Tbl1] GROUP BY A, B").GetString(2, -1, " ", "`n")
$oXDb.Close()
```

just to show that syntax is just syntax.

Comment: +1, I started an answer in VBA with dictionary but your solution is simplier.